# Cannot get an Image from ImageButton because returns null

Tags: android, sqlite, android-imagebutton

I have an activity which is populated with data from sqlite.

I want to update the data and I click my Update Button, and I see all my data including the image in ImageButton loaded from my sqlite db.

I try to get the already saved and displayed image with

```
ImageButton Logo;
Drawabable drawableLogo = Logo.getDrawable();
```

but I get null ! How I am getting null if the Logo imagebutton has an Image ?

What I am forgetting here?

thank you

Comment: You forgot to initialize the "Logo" button.

Comment: By initialize you mean logo = (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.mylogo); I have this in my onCreate Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BitmapDrawable` to get bitmap from ImageView/ImageButton.

```
Bitmap drawableLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) Logo.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work and getting it first as a bitmap before converted to byte[]

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageButton Logo; // Logo??
Drawabable drawableLogo = Logo.getDrawable();

ImageButton logo;  
logo = (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.mylogo):
Drawabable drawableLogo = logo.getDrawable();
```

so

```
Drawabable drawableLogo = new Drawable():
drawableLogo = logo.getDrawable();
```

Comment: I have my logo = (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.mylogo); already on create and the Drawable drawableLogo = Logo.getDrawable(); in my Save button

Comment: You cannot use Drawable drawableLogo = new Drawable():
drawableLogo = logo.getDrawable() because it wants to implement associated methods and If I do, it wants drawableLogo to declared as final  but if you do does not work